Duplicate mapping error for composite primary key references in Spring Boot JPA
I'm implementing a database layer for a Spring Boot application with JPA. I'm getting the following error.
[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'env_id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.sample.app.entity.GroupResourceAllocation' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)

Here's the database tables that I'm referring to,

following are the implemented entity classes:
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Environment {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "env_id")
    private Long envId;

    private String name;
    private String status;
}


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserId id;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String status;

    @MapsId("envId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "env_id")
    private Environment environment;
}


import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Data
@Embeddable
public class UserId implements Serializable {
    private Long envId;
    private Long empId;
}


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Data
public class Group {
    @EmbeddedId
    private GroupId id;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String status;

    @MapsId("envId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "env_id")
    private Environment environment;
}


import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Data
@Embeddable
public class GroupId implements Serializable {
    private Long envId;
    private String groupName;
}


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Data
public class Resource {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ResourceId id;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String status;

    @MapsId("envId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "env_id")
    private Environment environment;
}


import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Data
@Embeddable
public class ResourceId implements Serializable {
    private Long envId;
    private String resourceName;
}


import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class GroupResourceAllocation {
    @EmbeddedId
    private GroupResourceAllocationId id;

    private String status;

    @MapsId("envId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "env_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Environment environment;

    @MapsId("groupName")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "env_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "group_name")
    })
    private Group group;

    @MapsId("resourceName")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "env_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "resource_name")
    })
    private Resource resource;
}


import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Data
@Embeddable
public class GroupResourceAllocationId implements Serializable {
    private Long envId;
    private String groupName;
    private String resourceName;
}

I'm expecting a solution for this, it would be helpful if someone could share a solution/resources to get this resolved.

Your DB schema looks unusual. Can you change it?

Because you have 2 or more records with same composite primary key.
Solution: Has few different solution, you can add a dummy key use UUIDv4, and no need care about composite key.
@Entity
class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID dummyID;

